# Wait for MSU install with powerhsell

Tags: powershell, installation, invoke

In the begining of my script I check some parameters and in particular the version of powershell.
If the version of powershell is lt 4 I want to install the new version (Windows6.1-KB2819745-x64-MultiPkg.msu).
This script will be convert in .exe with powershell studio.
My problem is I can launch the installation of powershell silently but I want to wait the end of installation and the return code to check if the installation done correctly and before continue the execution of the script I need this installation done.

I try this but is not working (the script not wait for end of installation) :

```
Invoke-Expression "C:\PowershellSources\PS4_Windows6.1-KB2819745-x64-MultiPkg.msu /quiet / norestart /wait" 
    #verification of the powershell version
    $PowershellVersion = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major

    If ($PowershellVersion -lt "4")
    {
        $PowershellInstalled = $False
    }
    Else
    {
        $PowershellInstalled = $true
    }

    If (($LastexitCode -eq 0) -and ($PowershellInstalled -eq $true))
    {
        ([System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Installation Done Properly
Can Continue", "Success", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information) -eq "OK")
    }

    Else
    {
        ([System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Error during installation of Powershell`
please contact system_admin@xxx.com", "ERROR", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error) -eq "OK")
    Exit    
    }
```

I try this too :

```
$StartInstall = (& wusa "C:\PowershellSources\PS4_Windows6.1-KB2819745-x64-MultiPkg.msu" /quiet /norestart)

        ---------------------------------------
    #Wait for end of Powershell Installation
    #---------------------------------------

    #Define the process to wait in $processtargettowait
    $ProcesstargetToWait = "wusa"
    #Get the complet name of the process
    $ProcessToWait = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.ProcessName -like $ProcesstargetToWait }
    #Tant que le process est lancé (ie : while the process is running = while ($process) = $true
    While ($ProcessToWait)
    {
        #on recheck le process
        $ProcessToWait = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.ProcessName -like $ProcesstargetToWait }
        #message indiquant que l'installation est toujours en cours
        ([System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please Relax and wait the end of installation of POWERSHELL`nI'm Working for you.", "Please Wait", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information) -eq "OK")
        #on attend Xsec avant le prochain check
        start-sleep -Seconds 2
    }#end While loop

    #----------------------------------------------
    #END of Wait for end of Powershell Installation
    #----------------------------------------------
```

Some one have an idea to solved that ?

Thanks a lot scripting guys !

Regards
Julien

Comment: Hi, only with -wait parameter I have an access denied, I'm local admin of the computer :

Comment: $ProcessToStart = "C:\PowershellSources\PS4_Windows6.1-KB2819745-x64-MultiPkg.msu"
  $ArgumentList = "/q /norestart"
  $startInstall = (Start-Process $ProcessToStart $ArgumentList -wait)
  $startInstall

Answer (score 1):

`Start-Process` has a `-wait` switch you can use to wait for a process to terminate prior to continuing.

Comment: HI thanks for reply, I have some issue with - wait. I have an access denied but I'm local admin on this computer. It's seem that the issue is due to the .msu format because with and .msi there is no problem, do you have an idea for a work arround ?